# using OAuth in node application

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I am developing an application which is only going to be required to be used by a few people within the organisation. It is being developed using Yeoman and expressJS.

What i need to do is only authenticate a few users to use their google accounts as they require access to google calendars etc which they currently share within their organisation. The only difference is that it will be used within the application.

The users will need to login but trying to find out how i can use their google accounts to login and colloborate?

I only want to limit it to certain users.

Hope someone can assist.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) is a popular choice of authentication/authorisation library. You can easily integrate it with express. It has a strategy for google account using OAuth as [passport-google-oauth](https://npmjs.org/package/passport-google-oauth).

Comment: Thanks for that. Have seen this before. But in regards to refresh tokens how would these work as i need to store these? How often to the tokens refresh and how can this be check as I dont the user to authenticate everytime. I will be create a normal user and password. Then in a settings area they will need to link the google account to their user.

Comment: Yes, you would need to store them. Access token will be used with the calender API. One approach is to use them until the API detects timeout/expiry. Then use refreshtoken to update accesstoken. You will have to synergize your own user account with their google accounts. This authentication route should be called only once to set the tokens, which you will use till user is logged in. See the example https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/master/examples/oauth2/app.js.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but it seems very straightforward. 
If you have ever used the google API the examples seem easy to understand.

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/